# How do I calculate spikes in data over the last x amount of minutes in QuestDB

Tags: sql, questdb

I have a table CPU with some metrics coming in over Influx line protocol, how can I run a query that tells me if data has exceeded a certain threshold in the last x minutes,

I am trying to do something like:

```sql
select usage_system, timestamp
from cpu
Where usage_system > 20
```

But I have all records returned. For the time range, I don't want to hardcode timestamps or have to replace it with the current time to get a relative query

| usage | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 27.399999999906 | 2021-04-14T12:02:30.000000Z |
| 26.400000000139 | 2021-04-14T12:02:30.000000Z |
| 25.666666666899 | 2021-04-14T12:02:30.000000Z |
| ... | ... |

Ideally I would like to be able to check if usage is above an average, but above hardcoded value is fine for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will dynamically filter the last 5 minutes on the timestamp field and will return rows based on a hardcoded value (when `usage_system` is above `20`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM cpu
WHERE usage_system > 20
AND timestamp > dateadd('m', -5, now());
```

If you want to add some more details to the query, you can cross join an aggregate value:

```sql
WITH avg_usage AS (select avg(usage_system) average FROM cpu)
SELECT timestamp, cpu.usage_system usage, average, cpu.usage_system > avg_usage.average above_average
FROM cpu CROSS JOIN avg_usage
Where timestamp > dateadd('m', -5, now());
```

This will add a boolean column `above_average` and will be true or false depending on whether the row's `usage_system` is above the aggregate:

| timestamp | usage | average | above_average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-14T13:30:00.000000Z | 20 | 10 | true |
| 2021-04-14T13:30:00.000000Z | 5 | 10 | false |

If you want all columns, it might be useful to move this filter down into the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
WITH avg_usage AS (select avg(usage_system) average FROM cpu)
SELECT *
FROM cpu CROSS JOIN avg_usage
WHERE timestamp > dateadd('m', -5, now())
AND cpu.usage_system > avg_usage.average;
```

This will then allow to do more complex filtering, such as returning all rows which are in a certain percentile, like the following which will return rows where the `usage_system` is above 80% of the recorded maximum in the last 5 minutes (i.e. highest by CPU usage):

```sql
WITH max_usage AS (select max(usage_system) maximum FROM cpu)
SELECT *
FROM cpu CROSS JOIN max_usage
WHERE timestamp > dateadd('m', -5, now())
AND cpu.usage_system > (max_usage.maximum / 100 * 80);
```

**edit:** the last query was based on the example in the QuestDB [WITH keyword documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/with#examples)